# Why is the equation for its distance from the $x$ axis is twice that of its distance from the $y$ axis $y = 2x$?

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have an understanding problem that I need to clarify..

The equation of line $L$ is $2y = -5x + 10$.  A point $P$ lies on the line such that its "distance from the $x$ axis is twice that of its distance from the $y$ axis". Find the coordinates of $P$.

For the sentence that I quoted above ...

Why is the equation for that sentence: $y = 2x$

Thanks for your help in advance ..

Comment: @Théophile yes ! Sorry it was a typo

Comment: A point on the line $y=2x$ is always of the form $(a,2a)$ for some number $a$. The distance of $(a,2a)$ to the $y$-axis is $a$ and to the $x$-axis is $2a$, the double (make a sketch!).

Comment: Strictly speaking, the distance of a point $(x,y)$ from the $x$ axis is $\lvert y \rvert$. The distance _above_ the $x$ axis is $y$. The equation for "distance from the $x$ axis is twice that of its distance from the $y$ axis" is actually $\lvert y \rvert = 2\lvert x \rvert$. Unless there are additional constraints on the problem (such as, $P$ is in the first quadrant) there are two solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Technically the equation for the sentence is $|y| = 2|x|$.  The equation give you all of the points where the distance to the x axis is twice the distance to the y axis.  $|x|$ is distance to the y axis.  If you imagine drawing a line straight from the y axis to some point then the length of that line will be the x coordinate of the point.  The same is true for the x axis except $|y|$ is the distance.

To find the point (or points since there may be more than on answer) you have to find the points where the statement $|y| = 2|x|$ is true and that happen to lie on the line $2y = -5x + 10$.  You have have a system of two equations with two variables that you can solve using one of the methods that you have been taught.